# How to use several wp_ajax_ functions for different queries?

Tags: ajax

I am working on getting multiple functions to work with `wp_ajax_` and the first two functions fire just fine. However I have the need for a completely new query that will take advantage of AJAX also.

- Should I beef up my first function with conditionals? Or
- Can I `init` more than one `wp_ajax_` function like my code below?

My code so far:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_ajax_init' );
function my_ajax_init() {
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_search', 'my_ajax_search');// works
   add_action('wp_ajax_wpa56343_search', 'my_ajax_search'); // works

   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nogeo_results', 'nogeo_search'); // does not
   add_action('wp_ajax_nogeo_results', 'nogeo_search'); // does not
}
```

`my_ajax_search` is functioning fine with my JS AJAX calls. `nogeo_search` is not. My question is - **is what I am doing to declare my ajax functions correct?** If it is not correct please explain how to use `wp_ajax_` with multiple callback functions.

Comment: I cannot get any code to format above. So sorry

Comment: The markdown (among other things) sometimes has trouble with code that follows a list. I added a line of "normal" text to force it to behave.

Comment: Your code is fine. The second question is a matter of preference and the first (and last) are not answerable, in my opinion, without more information.

Comment: The conditional question was based on if using multiple wp_ajax_ functions is a bad idea. I'd be forced to send extra post vars etc to conditional my existing query. Having trouble getting all this to output... Thanks for the good answers.

Comment: I haven't answered anything yet and honestly the question is dangerously close to deserving an "unclear what you are asking" close vote.

Comment: Why do you gotta be mean?

Comment: Mean? No idea what you mean. Your question/problem is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get multiple wp_ajax_ functions to declare callback functions like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_ajax_init' );
function my_ajax_init() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_search', 'first_search');
    add_action('wp_ajax_wpa56343_search', 'first_search');
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_ajax_no_geo_init' );
function my_ajax_no_geo_init() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nogeo_results', 'second_search');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nogeo_results', 'second_search');
}
```

Comment: upvoted to get this question out of the unanswered questions queue on the site, but the code here is virtually the same as in the question.